# How to change path for i18n angular translate module files in angular app production build

Tags: angular, angular-i18n

I want to place my application in http://example.com/my_dir path, first of all I had to add to my build command an option `build --prod --base-href=/my_dir/`. All works fine but I have a problem only with translator files. Normaly I kept them in assets/i18n/ directory, how to change request path for this file to /my_dir/assetes/i18n ?

I use Angular 8 and TranslateModule

This is my config in app.module.ts

```
import {TranslateModule, TranslateLoader} from "@ngx-translate/core";
import {TranslateHttpLoader} from "@ngx-translate/http-loader";

// AoT requires an exported function for factories
export function HttpLoaderFactory(httpClient: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(httpClient);
}

imports: [
...,
TranslateModule.forRoot({
 loader: {
  provide: TranslateLoader,
  useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
  deps: [HttpClient]
 }
})
]
```

**RESOLVED**
I added here to TranslateHttpLoader(httpClient)

```
// AoT requires an exported function for factories
export function HttpLoaderFactory(httpClient: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(httpClient);
}
```

additional prefix option
 `return new TranslateHttpLoader(httpClient, '/my_dir/assets/i18n/');`

and it works fine